# Makefile: different variable's value based on rule

Tags: makefile

I've got the following situation in my makefile:

```
SDLINC_NOVA = -I/usr/local/lib/sdl_2.0.5/include/SDL2 -D_REENTRANT
SDLLIB_NOVA = -L/usr/local/lib/sdl_2.0.5/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/sdl_2.0.5/lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
SDLINC_MAC  = -I/usr/local/SDL/include -D_REENTRANT
SDLLIB_MAC  = -L/usr/local/SDL/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/SDL/lib -Wl,-install_name,--enable-new-dtags -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
....
.PHONY: all nova mac clean

all: nova

nova: SDLINC = $(SDLINC_NOVA)
nova: SDLLIB = $(SDLLIB_NOVA)
nova: build
mac: SDLINC = $(SDLINC_MAC)
mac: SDLLIB = $(SDLLIB_MAC)
mac: build

build: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(SDLLIB) -o $@

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SDLINC) -c $< -o $@
```

It feels like I'm doing something wrong.. Basically the `SDLINC` and `SDLLIB` variables should contain different value based on the rule that is called, and then the `build` rule should be called.

What is the right convention to achieve that in a makefile?

Comment: I suppose `mac` means that you are building in Mac OS, but what is Nova then?

Comment: A linux server which I need my project to work on, and don't have sanction there. So I want to `make mac` to debug on my machine, but `make` / `make nova` to work as default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the right approach would be not to have two different rules for Mac and Linux. This is because both of those are Unix-based systems and are quite common.

The approach is to automatically detect the system you are running on, this can be done using `uname` shell command:

```
 OS := $(shell uname)
 ifeq ($(OS), Darwin)
        OS := mac
 else ifeq ($(OS), Linux)
        OS := linux
 else
        $(info Warning: unknown OS, assuming linux)
        OS := linux
 endif
```

And then just add `ifeq` conditions to assign your variables:

```
ifeq ($(OS), linux)
    SDLINC = $(SDLINC_NOVA)
    SDLLIB = $(SDLLIB_NOVA)
else ifeq ($(OS), mac)
    SDLINC = $(SDLINC_MAC)
    SDLLIB = $(SDLLIB_MAC)
endif
```

and remove your rules for `mac` and `nova`, now you only need one `build` rule.

You can check what is the output of `uname` command on your Nova machine and adjust it accordingly in your makefile, but I'm pretty sure it will be `Linux`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about something like that, but on the Nova machine they don't have `shell` - I'm getting `shell: Command not found` through SSH. Kinda weird, but I gotta deal with that. Are there other known options? Ideally, I might want to add Windows in the future, but I don't want to deal with that right now.

Comment: so, you are not able to connect to Nova via SSH at all? Perhaps you don't have permissions, but build will still have access to shell, you should try.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I am able to connect via SSH of course, it's just that the machine doesn't have the `shell` command. I don't know what variant of linux it is, but it just doesn't have it. And I cannot `apt-get install shell` there.

Comment: you don't need `shell` command, just type `uname` in the command line

Comment: My bad, I guess I'm not familiar enough with unix after all. Thank you.

Comment: `$(shell XXX)` in the `makefile` just instructs `make` to execute `XXX` from command line and substitute output back to makefile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164157/discussion-between-galah92-and-igagis).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `build` target is a *common prerequisite* of both `nova` and `mac`. Therefore, the rule for the target `build` is only matched once. That is, it is matched for the first target that requires it, then it remains updated for the second target that requires it.

You can set up your makefile, so that those targets above depend on different prerequisites:

```
nova: SDLINC = $(SDLINC_NOVA)
nova: SDLLIB = $(SDLLIB_NOVA)
nova: build-nova

mac: SDLINC = $(SDLINC_MAC)
mac: SDLLIB = $(SDLLIB_MAC)
mac: build-mac
```

With this new setup, `mac` depends on `build-mac` and `nova` depends on `build-nova`.

Then, by adding the following rule:

```
build-nova build-mac:
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory $(TARGET)
```

its recipe will be executed for each target (i.e.: `build-nova` and `build-mac`) *separately*.

What the recipe of that rule does is to call `make` recursively for the target specified (i.e.: the result of expanding `TARGET`). You need however to export both `SDLINC` and `SDLLIB` variables in your makefile, so that the new process which runs `make` obtains them:

```
export SDLINC
export SDLLIB
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need them to run separately. Ideally, on one machine I would want to use `make nova` and on other `make mac`, where the only change is the `inc` and `lib` paths. Why would I want another makefile, and dealing with exporting make variables? Why would I want to separate the `build` command?

Comment: @galah92 If you are running `make` as you've just said (i.e.: by running `make nova` or `make mac`), then I see no problem with your current makefile.